# java.lang.VerifyError after running the DataNucleus Enhancer

Tags: java, datanucleus

I got a strange behavior after running the datanucleus enhancer. And then trying to generate the EntityManagerFactory, I ran in an java.lang.VerifyError, which is

```
 method: setItem signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;)V) Incompatible argument to function" type="java.lang.VerifyError">java.lang.VerifyError: (class: de/suur/wr/generated/FlagType$FlagTypeRemoveFlagsItem, method: setItem signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;)V) Incompatible argument to function
```

The original declaration of the method is:

```
    public void setItem(String value) {
        this.item = value;
    }
```

I figured out that java adds some synthetic bridge  methods to the bytecode, which would indeed match the error (see below). But usually this methods can coexist  peacefully. Maybe the error is not related to the enhancer at all, but however I have no other intuition I thought it is related. 
   What could be the reasons?

```
  // Method descriptor #53 (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  // Stack: 2, Locals: 2
  public bridge synthetic void setItem(java.lang.Object arg0);
  0  aload_0 [this]
  1  aload_1 [arg0]
  2  checkcast java.lang.String [54]
  5  invokevirtual    de.suur.wr.generated.FlagType$FlagTypeRemoveFlagsItem.setItem(java.lang.String) : void [56]
  8  return
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 1]
```

and the original method:

```
 // Method descriptor #36 (Ljava/lang/String;)V
 // Stack: 2, Locals: 2
 public void setItem(java.lang.String value);
  0  aload_0 [this]
  1  aload_1 [value]
  2  putfield de.suur.wr.generated.FlagType$FlagTypeRemoveFlagsItem.item : java.lang.String [33]
  5  return
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 314]
    [pc: 5, line: 315]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 6] local: this index: 0 type: de.suur.wr.generated.FlagType.FlagTypeRemoveFlagsItem
    [pc: 0, pc: 6] local: value index: 1 type: java.lang.String
```

I'm used the  datanucleus(DN) and the datanucleus maven plugin(DNM2) in servile combinations: (DN,DNM2)  1.1.4 , 2.0.0 and 2.1.1, 2.1.1  . The stacktrace is

```
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AbstractAnnotationReader.getJavaBeanAccessorAnnotationsForClass(AbstractAnnotationReader.java:238)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously if using DN v1.1 then you should be using the DN M2 plugin v1.1 (which uses enhancer v1.1). Needless to say we only "support" current versions and neither of those are in that category

Comment: Well I thought so too, then I tried different versions with the same effect, so in the end I retried with DNv.1.1.4 and DN M2v1.1.4. , and with 2.1.1 (DN M2 and DN), same same.